# Carrying through Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

i've got function that checks value in array

```
    const arr = [10,20,30];
    const check = (needle) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                arr.includes(needle) ? resolve('err') : reject('err');
            })
        };
```

and works like this in custom case

```
checkPermissionByRole(100)
            .then(val => console.log(val))
            .catch( err => console.log(err)) // gives 'err' as expected
```

But i wanted to make something like

```
const arr = [10,20,30];
const second = [40,50,60];

const check = (needle) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    arr.includes(needle) ? resolve('err') : // call check again but with another array to check in
                })
            };
```

if a promise gives me a rejected value, check it again with the same function(and the same argument) that gives me a promise, but list / array (`arr` one) should be `second` instead of `arr`. Thought i could do it with a carrying construction, and if not, give me some bread for thinking

Comment: Why are you promisifying function that has absolutely no asynchronism?

Comment: @JaromandaX because this is just simplified case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if `needle` is contained in any of two arrays, you can do:

```
(arr.includes(needle) || second.includes(needle)) ? resolve('err') : reject('err');
```

Comment: nice way simpler then carrying.

Comment: hm , seems like it's ok , but is it reasonable to make like i've posted in a question? Because i wanted to make some logic "in between". In case if `needle` failed to be found in first array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [10,20,30];
const second = [40,50,60];

const check = (needle) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    arr.includes(needle) && resolve('err1') ||
    second.includes(needle) && resolve('err2') || reject('err');
  })
};
```

Comment: Very clumsy and harder to read way to check it. See hsz answer.